# Spring MVC Annotation Validation message bundle priority

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller, annotations

I have a spring mvc form field annotated like:

```
public class RegisterForm {
   @NotEmpty
   private String category;
```

My message bundle has two entries related

```
NotEmpty= Value must be provided.
NotEmpty.registerForm.category= Category must be provided
```

While I was trying to override the message conventionally, it always picks the first one "Value must be provided"

I also tried like

```
@NotEmpty(message="Category must be provided")
```

It shows the same.

In case I remove "NotEmpty" entry from message bundle it works.

Is there a compact way to override this while keeping the default message?

Comment: How do you validate the form? In a `@Controller`? Can you post the code?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String doRegister(@Valid final RegisterForm registerForm, final BindingResult bindingResult, ... // via Valid annotation

Comment: in the code snippet the form class is `RegisterPersonaForm` but in the question is `RegisterForm`... I suspect that in your message bundle you should have key `NotEmpty.registerPersonaForm.category` instead of `NotEmpty.registerForm.category`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I corrected this. It's RegisterForm. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Everything works as you expect now, right?

Comment: No, sorry, I meant that I corrected the snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188158/discussion-between-caco3-and-esat).